# Read One Cell and Copy to Another Only Upon Opening Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy the data in cell c3 to cell i11 when I open my spreadsheet. I do not want i11 to change after this action until I reopen the spreadsheet.

Comment: Investigate `Workbook_Open()`

Comment: Clarification: is there only one worksheet in the workbook?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the code in the `ThisWorkbook` part of your projects. Select `Workbook` and `Open` or use the following code.

The working formula is the value you see me do below, but this can be achieved a number of way such as using `Cells(3,3).Value`. Additionally the way the sheet is referenced can vary. I put both the `Activesheet` reference and a explicit sheet reference, depending how your sheet is structured you may have to use one over the other, but choose one below and see how your sheet handles it and if adjustments are needed.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
'Use one of these depending on how your sheet opens

ActiveSheet.Range("I11").Value = ActiveSheet.Range("C3").Value

Worksheet("YourWorksheetHere").Range("I11").Value = Worksheet("YourWorksheetHere").Range("C3").Value

End Sub
```